References for a Bernoulli number series identity
From identities for the digamma function follows the Riemann zeta / Bernoulli number identity
$$ 1 = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\zeta\left(2n\right)\ \frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)\left(n+1\right)} =  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (2\pi)^{2n}  \frac{|Ber_{2n}|}{ (2n)!} \ \frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)\left(n+1\right)},$$
with the conventional Bernoulli numbers defined by the e.g.f.
$\frac{t}{e^t-1} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}Ber_n\frac{t^n}{n!}$.
I'm looking for references for this identity.

For positive even integers $n$, $\zeta(n)=Ber_n\dfrac{(-1)^{\frac n2-1}(2\pi)^n}{2n!}$

@J.W.Tanner, hence the last equality follows from the first.
